# How to implement delete Intermediate table

Tags: sql

In my Java program, I want to achieve such a piece of SQL, when delete table A with code using for condition,and `delete Table B(linkId=deleted ids of Table A)`

Table A:

```
===============================================
id          |        code      |    names     |
===============================================
1           |          A       |    name1     |
2           |          A       |    name2     |
3           |          A       |    name3     |
4           |          B       |    name4     |
5           |          B       |    name5     |
6           |          B       |    name6     |
7           |          B       |    name7     |
8           |          C       |    name8     |
```

Table B( Intermediate table):

```
================================
id          |       linkId     |...
================================
1           |          1       |...
2           |          2       |...
3           |          2       |...
4           |          2       |...
5           |          3       |...
6           |          7       |...
7           |          8       |...
8           |          8       |...
```

like this:

```
delete from A where code = A
delete from B where linkId =(1,2,3)
```

**How to use an sql statement to achieve?**

Comment: If you own the db, you can add a foreign key with the 'on delete cascade' option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, just change the order of deletion.

```
-- Delete from TableB (Remove all related records from the child table)
DELETE FROM
  TableB
WHERE
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE TableB.LinkId = TableA.id AND TableA.code = 'A');

-- Delete from TableA (Remove the record from the parent table)
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE code = 'A';
```

**Consider to do all actions related to this multi-table deletinon in a transaction to prevent data loss when one of the statements fails.**

[Transactions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

[Transactions in Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)

[Transactions in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If there can't be lines in B with ids not existing in a you can write

```
delete from B where not exists ( select 1 from A where A.id=B.linkId);
```

Otherwise you should perform the delete in B before deleting from A to make sure the deleted rows are not definitiley lost.